# How to reverse NSObject.FromObject back to a regular C# type

Tags: monomac, xamarin.mac

What is the reverse of NSObject.FromObject, e.g., getting a regular C# object back out of an NSObject. Understandably, this could only work for simple types.

**Update.** Let's say I even know the type - but not before runtime. I tried

```
Convert.ChangeType (value, info.PropertyType, null)
```

but i get a message that "Value is not a convertible object: MonoMac.Foundation.NSString to System.String".

**Update 2.** How FromObject works:

```cs
using MonoMac.ObjCRuntime;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
public static NSObject FromObject (object obj)
{
    NSObject result;
    if (obj == null)
    {
        result = NSNull.Null;
    }
    else
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType ();
        if (type == typeof(NSObject) || type.IsSubclassOf (typeof(NSObject)))
        {
            result = (NSObject)obj;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (Type.GetTypeCode (type))
            {
            case 3:
                result = new NSNumber ((bool)obj);
                return result;
            case 4:
                result = new NSNumber ((ushort)((char)obj));
                return result;
            case 5:
                result = new NSNumber ((sbyte)obj);
                return result;
            case 6:
                result = new NSNumber ((byte)obj);
                return result;
            case 7:
                result = new NSNumber ((short)obj);
                return result;
            case 8:
                result = new NSNumber ((ushort)obj);
                return result;
            case 9:
                result = new NSNumber ((int)obj);
                return result;
            case 10:
                result = new NSNumber ((uint)obj);
                return result;
            case 11:
                result = new NSNumber ((long)obj);
                return result;
            case 12:
                result = new NSNumber ((ulong)obj);
                return result;
            case 13:
                result = new NSNumber ((float)obj);
                return result;
            case 14:
                result = new NSNumber ((double)obj);
                return result;
            case 18:
                result = new NSString ((string)obj);
                return result;
            }
            if (type == typeof(IntPtr))
            {
                result = NSValue.ValueFromPointer ((IntPtr)obj);
            }
            else
            {
                if (type == typeof(SizeF))
                {
                    result = NSValue.FromSizeF ((SizeF)obj);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (type == typeof(RectangleF))
                    {
                        result = NSValue.FromRectangleF ((RectangleF)obj);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (type == typeof(PointF))
                        {
                            result = NSValue.FromPointF ((PointF)obj);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            INativeObject nativeObject = obj as INativeObject;
                            if (nativeObject != null)
                            {
                                result = Runtime.GetNSObject (nativeObject.Handle);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                result = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like the `FromObject` conversion, you have to handle that case by case.

for `NSNumber`s, use explicit casting (works for bool as well):

```cs
NSNumber number;
double d = (double)number;
```

for `NSString`s, implicit conversion even work:

```cs
NSString nsstring;
string converted = nsstring;
```

But I guess you already figured the value types conversions.

For reference type, all types deriving from `NSObject` (that's the case for most of the objects you want to pass back and forth to native) have a constructor overload taking an `IntPtr` as argument. use that.

```cs
NSObject native;
var label = new UILabel (native.Handle);
```

That being said, the `NSObject` is redundant. Your native library could just return an `IntPtr` (`void*`) you could use to recreate your objects. You DON'T have to do this:

```cs
IntPtr ptr;
NSObject nsobject = new NSObject (ptr);
```